# Duplicate id layout error

Tags: android, textview

I've got the following error in a TextView inside my layout.

> Duplicate id @+id/communications, already defined earlier in this
>   layout

But it is not duplicated. I don't know why and what causes this error. Please help!

Comment: there 2 communications ids in same layout...

Comment: If you are using `eclipse` just click on the `communication` id in xml with `ctrl` key holding to see where the other id is located.

Comment: @DIVA No, it is NOT duplicated, I'm 100% sure

Comment: @NadeemIqbal It does nothing

Comment: do file seearch in eclipse with "communication" go to serach-->file-->put communication it will give u all referance telll me how many u got..

Comment: Please post your xml

Answer (score 5):

Just `Clean` the project. Sometimes it is the issue of the eclipse that it does not reindex/rebuild the R file containing all the resources IDs. So clean should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Lint error message, which means that you have assigned the same @+id to two or more elements (Views) in your layout.xml file.

Just double click on the error message under Lint Warning and it will take you to the place where you have a conflict of Duplicate id. Rename it to something unique and the issue will be resolved.