# How do I fix Error: Duplicate id in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I getting

> Error:(7) Error: Duplicate id @+id/item, already defined earlier in
>   this layout [DuplicateIds]'

I'm using Android Studio. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate id layout error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770973/duplicate-id-layout-error)

Comment: Check if you have two elements with the same id, if not just try to clean the project and if still not working share your XML code.

Answer (score 4):

If you using text layout and check the xml code for finding the red line(indication of error) in android studio.
If you have than change the value like shown in the image and finally clean and build the project.

**Error Image**

[image: Error Image]

**After change the id**

[image: After change the id]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you had defined two view with the same id.Check your code.(ctrl+f)
It is not the as's fault.